# How to fix vba code when it seems to not be reading my conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, excellibrary

The vba code seems to not be reading my conditions

I tried ="*condition*" and now with like and none of them seem to work

This is my code. The code is running with no issues but nothing is getting copied where it should (cells &j)

please help help help

```
Sub formatpkg()

Dim i, lrow, j, nextl As Integer
Dim val, size, recipe As String


lrow = 5231

For i = 1 To lrow
val = Worksheets("PKG").Range("a" & i).Value
j = 1
If val Like "Recipe Slot*" Then
j = j + 1
Worksheets("Results").Range("a" & j).Value = val
ElseIf val Like "Unit Weight*" Then
Worksheets("Results").Range("b" & j).Value = val
ElseIf UCase(Left(val, 2)) Like "GC" Then
Worksheets("Results").Range("C" & j).Value = val
Else
i = i + 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about reading conditions is incorrect. Using debug.print, breaks, msgbox, watch window, etc. will show that the conditions are being read correctly.

One problem is that you have `j = 1` inside your loop, so you keep resetting the value every time you go through the loop. Move it outside the loop, or get rid of it.

Another problem is that you have `i = i + 1` inside your loop. You don't use this statement in this kind of loop. Each time your loop hits the `Next` statement, it moves to the next value of `i`.

Best practice is to use spacing and indentation in code, exactly because it helps make this kind of mistake easier to see. Making code easier to read is much more important than saving a few letters or lines.

Have made some other corrections to your declarations and example of how to test your theory about conditions.

```
Sub formatpkg()

Dim i As Long, lrow As Long, j As Long, nextl As Long
Dim val As String, size As String, recipe As String

lrow = 5231
j = 1   'Or j = 0, or delete this line

For i = 1 To lrow
    
    val = Worksheets("PKG").Range("a" & i).Value
        
    If val Like "Recipe Slot*" Then
        Debug.Print "Row " & i, val, "matches Recipe Slot" 'example of how to use debug.print to check your code
        j = j + 1
        Worksheets("Results").Range("a" & j).Value = val
    ElseIf val Like "Unit Weight*" Then
        Worksheets("Results").Range("b" & j).Value = val
    ElseIf UCase(Left(val, 2)) Like "GC" Then
        Worksheets("Results").Range("C" & j).Value = val
    Else
        Debug.Print "Row " & i, val, "no match" 'example of how to use debug.print to check your code
    End If

Next

End Sub
```